# Access Python Script in Python Toolbox

Tags: python, arcgis, esri

I have downloaded a python toolbox for ArcGIS yesterday to help me in a project. At this time, I want to learn better of what's inside it and also change some part of the code.

Is there any way that I can do it? An explanation or a link to the answer source would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Surely the package you downloaded has a documentation page.  Python modules are delivered in source form, so you can go look at whatever you want.